# How to delete scoped_model state?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am use `scoped_model` for handle app state but I need to wipe all stored state (for example on user sign out).

How to delete all state store in `scoped_model`?

I know can just set state value to null. For example:

```
var = null
```

But this difficult to maintain if add new variable to state in `scoped_model`.

I am look for easy way to do.

**UPDATE:**

Example code store state:

First declare bool: `bool isUserRegister;`

Then set `isUserRegister = true;` after check database.

I have many of this type store in `scoped_model`. I need simple way to delete all state.

I am initialize model at top of widget hierarchy and wrap `MaterialApp` in `ScopedModel`:

```
void main() {
  runApp(new ExampleApp());
}

class ExampleApp extends StatelessWidget {

    final ExampleModel exampleModel = ExampleModel();

    //...

        return ScopedModel<ExampleModel>(
            model: exampleModel,
            child: MaterialApp(
```

Maybe one way is to initialize the model again?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method in your state class (the one that extends the `Model` class) that sets all your objects to null/empty arrays. It's hard to provide a certain answer given that you didn't provide any code to us.

---

Let's say that's your model:

```dart
class ExampleModel extends Model {
  String _someString = "some value";
  bool _someBool = false;

  void clear() {
    _someState = null;
    _someBool = null;
  }
}
```

You can just create a method like `clear()` and call it whenever you like.

Comment: Thanks for reply! I have add code in update. I know can just redeclare all variable to null but this not simple. For example if change or add more variable then I must also change this method that set all variable to null.

Comment: Thanks. I understand this. But for this every time I add a new variable to model I must again change the `clear()` method. This not efficient.